# AVPlayerViewController in UICollectionViewCell bug?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview, avplayerviewcontroller

In my UICollectionView i have a cell. This is my `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    var videoCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellVideo", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell

    let post = self.arrayOfDetails[indexPath.row]

    var myUrl = post.image // post.image is image url

    let fileUrl = NSURL(string: post.image)

    aPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: fileUrl)

    moviePlayerController.player = aPlayer
    moviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(8, 8, videoCell!.frame.size.width-16, 310)
    moviePlayerController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    moviePlayerController.view.sizeToFit()
    moviePlayerController.showsPlaybackControls = true
    videoCell!.addSubview(moviePlayerController.view)

    return videoCell!
}
```

The problem is that the AVPlayerViewController does not appear on each cell. But only on the cell that is under the one at i looking at, so if i scroll down in my UICollectionView and once a new cell appear on the screen, the AVPlayerViewController is on that cell and not the cell in the middel of screen. Any suggestions what might me wrong here?

Video here: https://vid.me/e/fU5X

Comment: It's the default behavior of the `UICollectionView` the cells are reusable. If you want to show the video if some specific cell, you need to specify in which one in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a new aPlayer and moviePlayerController for each cell which has the video in it. Something like this should do it:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        var videoCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellVideo", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell

        var aPlayer = AVPlayer()
        let moviePlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()

        let post = self.arrayOfDetails[indexPath.row]

        var myUrl = post.image // post.image is image url

        let fileUrl = NSURL(string: post.image)

        aPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: fileUrl)

        moviePlayerController.player = aPlayer
        moviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(8, 8, videoCell!.frame.size.width-16, 310)
        moviePlayerController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        moviePlayerController.view.sizeToFit()
        moviePlayerController.showsPlaybackControls = true
        videoCell!.addSubview(moviePlayerController.view)

        return videoCell!
    }
```

Comment: Since the cell is reused multiple AVPlayer's will be added to the same cell when user scroll the table view. It's important to remove the the AVPlayer(if exist) before adding the new one.

Comment: This needs to be updated, as its not correct and can cause readers multiple issues. As Rameez pointed out, scrolling causes the moviePlayerController to be added repeatedly to the same cell.